# How to make sure my ssid is being broadcasted in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.10

I couldn't find an answer to this seemingly basic question. My problem is that I'm trying to use my desktop pc as a wifi hotspot for my newly acquired nexus 7 tablet, but the tablet can't find the network. However, when trying to see if my desktop is actually broadcasting the ssid I couldn't find this option anywhere. This is my iwconfig dump:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"prueba"  
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: 2E:1C:2D:F7:90:FA   
          Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an ad-hoc wifi network; I don't think the Nexus 7 supports such networks.

See this bug report for further details: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35629

Comment: +1 for the link, but this doesn't solve the question. Do you know how to correctly create an infrastructure type of network? I tried simply switching that option in the network manager but then I couldn't broadcast it.

Comment: I don't think that all wifi cards support infrastructure mode. You might take a look at something like http://askubuntu.com/questions/106745/how-to-find-out-if-my-card-supports-infrastructure-mode for more ideas, though. I do think the best option overall is to buy a cheap wifi router, but maybe this doesn't work for you for whatever reason.